# How do I interpret the regression coefficients when making comparisons between the change of slope between control and disease?

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have 15 genes and two groups (58 control and 51 disease). I have relative abundances of the genes at two time points (time point 1 and a few years later time point 2, the average age difference is 4.9 years (max 11, min is 1).

I have basic line plots to visualise the change in the average expression at time point 1 and timepoint 2 for each group.

I would like to compare the change in slope between the second and first time point comparing the two groups.  I have subtracted the relative abundances at the first time point from the second for each group, for each gene (TP2-TP1). To make the comparison between the control and disease, I have then used a linear mixed effect model using the TP2-TP1 difference values and taking into consideration certain fixed and random effects.

Below is my code;

```
  output4 <- apply(control_disease[, 24:38], 2, function(i){
  fit <- lmer (i ~ disease + BMI + Age + Gender + Age.diff + (1|Fam), data = control_disease, REML=F, 
  na.action=na.omit)
  results <-summary(fit)$coef[2, c(1, 2, 5)]  ( this gets effect size, st.error and p value).
```

Control is marked as 0, disease is 4.

An effect size for gene 1 was -0.027 which was significant.  Am I interpreting this correctly if the change in slope between the second and first decreased by this amount in iT2D relative to control? In other words, the negative value suggests that the difference between TP2-TP1 is less in iT2D. ( I calculated the difference with the average TP2-TP1 relative abundance manually for this gene for both groups and this is the case).

The age difference coefficient for this is -0.0118. This suggests that for every unit increase in age difference you would expect this gene to decrease. A quick eye ball of the graph for this gene and in each group, the average gene expression of the line graph increases at the second time point, which confuses me.

In addition, as I am making the comparisons between the two groups, from this value I don’t believe I can determine the change in direction from TP2 to TP1, for instance, whether there is an increase or a decrease at TP2 compared to TP1 when just considering the disease group, without looking at the line graph?

Lastly, in my complete data set I have three groups. Control, Disease 1 and Disease 2.  Would a Repeated Measures ANOVA be useful to make the comparison between the change in slope between each group and also between the first and second-time point for each group? I am reading up about this now.

I would appreciate any help please.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite hard to interpret your results purely from words and some bits of code which we cannot reproduce. Below I try to comment based on my understanding. Suggest you update your post with more information:

> An effect size for gene 1 was -0.027 which was significant. Am I
>   interpreting this correctly if the change in slope between the second
>   and first decreased by this amount in iT2D relative to control?

I guess you are referring to the effect size of disease. I am not so sure it is the slope, because slope will be $\Delta(expression)/\Delta(age)$ and as far as I understood, you only have $\Delta(expression)$. So the coefficient is the change in gene expression from control to disease.

> However, as I am making the comparisons between the two groups, from
>   this value I don’t believe I can determine the change in direction
>   from TP2 to TP1, for instance, whether there is an increase or a
>   decrease at TP2 compared to TP1 when just considering the disease
>   group, without looking at the line graph?

This is more or less correct, as you have noticed, this is the effect of disease relative to control. So in R models, 0 (control) is taken as the reference level, and you estimate the effect of other groups relative to this reference. To know the change in direction (overall change of gene expression), you need to add the intercept. So if intercept is say 0.2, then overall change for disease = 0.2 + -0.027 = 0.19.. which makes it not much.

> Would a Repeated Measures ANOVA be useful to make the comparison
>   between the change in slope between each group and also between the
>   first and second-time point for each group?

Not very sure how you would set that up given the times are different.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. As I have calculated the TP2-TP1 relative abundance for each gene, I thought the effect size would be reflective of whether the difference between these timepoints is greater or less in control. With regards to change in expression/age,  if keeping with TP2-TP1, is this the age difference between these points? Also please could you let me know whether you would approach trying to identify the changes in slope between the two timepoints comparing both groups in a different way?

Comment: Also some genes decrease in expression at TP2 in the disease group and with control the expression has increased. So the direction of the lines are different with the line graph. I don't know whether doing TP2-TP1 is logical, as there is a greater change between TP1 and TP2 ( but in the negative direction for disease group). i.e Gene 1  Control (TP2-TP1; 0.745904-0.725227= 0.020677- line from TP1-TP2 goes up).     In the disease group (TP2-TP1 0.608-0.692= -0.084  -line from TP1-TP2 goes down). I guess, ignoring the signs, there is a bigger difference in disease.

Comment: so i think what you are doing is ok, i would explain the coefficient as overall increase in gene expression, after controlling for difference in time period.. The slight problem is this, you are expecting the age coefficient to be the same for both groups

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I do have the difference in age TP2-TP1 as a fixed effect, please could you let me know whether you would still advise having the change in TP2-TP1/age diff for each gene as the response variable?

Comment: ok so if you want to model it as a difference in slope, the model will be a bit more complicated. What you have done so far should be ok, it's a matter of explaining the coefficients. So in the sense of your data, you are modeling it like this, the change in expression with time is explained by the age coefficient, i.e x units per year, regarding of disease or not, let's say it's like a biological process for any human

Comment: The disease coefficient is like an effect on gene expression across all individuals who have disease versus no, averaged across the time span you measured. If the time differences we are talking about, don't vary too much in magnitude, we are not talking about 3-4 times differences, what you have is ok

Comment: Last question, promise. If for this particular gene with a significant coefficient of -0.027 for disease status, had a coefficient for the age difference of -0.01181. Please could you explain that in one line. Unfortunately, the time difference does vary quite a bit. The max is 11 years between Tp2 and Tp1, min is 1 year.

Comment: it will make more sense if you work this out in terms of averages, so let's say the average time difference is 1.5 (and Age variable is in years), then I would say for the average time of 1.5 years, you expect 1.5*-0.01181 = .. decrease in expression and for disease , we see this drop further by -0.027

Comment: hmmm ok may or may not be problem.. hey i cannot really tell. Meaning it really depends how strong of an effect age has. If the effect of disease far far outweights age, it will not matter. you need to look at your lines / data and see whether these coefficients or results make sense

Comment: ok now.. the question is, do you see a effect (TP2-TP1) in the control? I hope you control and disease are matched for age

Comment: Thank you for your replies. The data is a bit messy and I had too few subjects and unfortunately, they are not matched perfectly for age. Please could you clarify with regards to the effect in the control?

Comment: In the controls (if you have enough samples), you can guess how the gene expression will vary will age (normally). If this effect is not strong at all, like in the example you showed above, then however you model it, the effect of disease is there, and what you estimated should reflect the change in gene expression in disease

Comment: You can visualize this easily, by plotting the age difference vs change in expression, colored by disease/control..  see whether there's a pattern or really like 2 hugely different slopes. If you have little subjects, i am guessing you are unlikely to see something like this.

Comment: thank you for your help thus far. I will make a few plots to explore the data a bit more and will upvote later on today. I will also add any updates.

Comment: I would suggest standardizing the data (subtracting the mean (optional) and dividing by the standard deviation), and then compare slope changes over time between the groups. Logic: The non-control group may have more volatility and, at least, you may not want to ascribe professed differences based on volatility differences solely.

Comment: @AJKOER Thanks for your reply. The relative abundance values were already normalized and scaled (min/max) prior to TP2-TP1. Please could you advise whether with the difference values, to further standardize?

Comment: You may instituted this already, but have you attempted to develop 'best practices' based on a pathogen and it's variations that you understand so you can verify the accuracy of your methodology on detecting changes. At least, this may serve as a learning tool.